# Constructing an entire function which has a zero of order $k^2$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I realize that such a function must exist because of the Weierstrass Factorization theorem, but how do I find the explicit form of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{z^4}{k^4})^{k^2}$ will do. 
Note that this product converges based on the well known fact that 
$\prod(1-|a_n|)$ and $\sum |a_n|$ converge(diverge) simultaneity.

Comment: To be clear, here $\cap$ means product instead of intersection right?

Comment: Yes, of course, product. Sorry for the typo.